# How to use Polymer lifecycle hooks

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a component that contains video. My component is nested in a `dom-if` and can disappear. When this happens the video (and it sound) keep playing.

Is there a way in which my component can detect that is has  disappeared from the DOM? I have tried to use the 'detached' callback as described here: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements

```
Polymer({
  is: 'my-component-with-video',

  properties: {
     // some properties
  },

  detached: function() {
    console.log('Component detached');
    // more code to stop video
  },
```

but when my element is removed by the `dom-if` nothing happens, I don't see the `console.log` message. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two scenarios possible here:

1. You want your element to be discarded and recreated fresh when the condition changes.
2. You want to keep it in the dom but freeze it.

In the first case you need to add the `restamp` attribute to the `dom-if` to make sure the template DOM is destroyed, not hidden. By default the dom-if stamps the template at first initialization and then hides it from the view if the condition becomes falsy.

In the second case, the suggestion given by [Intervalia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1253074/intervalia) will not work, because the `dom-if` in "hide" mode does not detach anything from the DOM. Setting `restamp` attribute will make the `detached` callback run but then no point in pausing anything since the element will be discarded.
If you want to keep it in the DOM and freeze it's state you need to listen to `dom-change` event on the `dom-if` and run the `.pause()` accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

No need for any workaround other than simply using your dom-if and rather than

```
<dom-if if="[[condietionBoolean]]">
<your-video-element id="giveanId"></your-video-element>
</dom-if>
```

write the if statement like below and so each time your condition changes, you check and make sure the video is paused if when you like. See below.

```
...
<dom-if if="[[_shouldShowVideo(conditionBoolean)]]">
<your-video-element id="giveanId"></your-video-element>
</dom-if>

...

Polymer({
  is: 'my-component-with-video',

  properties: {

     conditionBoolean : {
        type: Boolean, 
     },

  },

_shouldShowVideo: function(conditionBoolean ) {
   if (!conditionBoolean) this.$$(#yourVideoElementId).pause();
   return conditionBoolean ;
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

In your detached function you need to get the Video Element and call `.pause()` on it.

You will probably also need to call `.pause()` when your condition changes that would cause the `dom-if` to remove the player.

Comment: That was what I was intending to do, but as Lukasz point out, I did not need to, because if the video is really detached it will automatically stop. So restamp on dom-if is the solution.

Comment: I don't know if you need it, but the advantage to calling `.pause()` is that you can also find out what `.currentTime` is and saving it off. Then you can resume at the previous `.currentTime` or at `0` to start from the beginning.